# How do I use jsdom with Gatsby (aka use webpack target node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gatsby, jsdom

I want to use [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) within a Gatsby project, in order to be able to load and render a separate webpage within a React component.

However, when I try to build with Gatsby, I get a series of Webpack errors which look like this:

> undefined failed
>
> Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> '/Users/john/WebstormProjects/analytics/web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr'

I think this may be because Webpack is using the 'web' target mode and not 'node'. I've tried putting a `webpack.config.js` file in the root directory:

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
}
```

However, this didn't do anything. I also tried to use `onCreateWebpackConfig`, but I'm not sure if this is correct, as I couldn't get this to work either:

```
//gatsby-node.ts
export { onCreateWebpackConfig } from "./src/gatsby/on-create-webpack-config";


// ./src/gatsby/on-create-webpack-config
export const onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions } : any) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    target: 'node',
  });
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use `jsdom` in a Gatsby project and if so, what do I need to do? If it's just to use the `target` mode, then:
2. How do I set the `target` mode in Gatsby to be `node` and not `web`?

Answer (score 0):

> 2. How do I set the target mode in Gatsby to be node and not web?

It looks like you can alter the webpack config to set the target:

```js
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();
  config.target = 'node';
  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config);
};
```

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/#modifying-the-babel-loader